# Java Menu Bar not appearing in Swing GUI despite setting to frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu, frame

I am writing a basic program in order to practice and learn using a swing GUI, i have built a frame with a basic menu, added this to the frame, yet for some reason when i run the program it doesnt appear in the frame.

```
public class GUITest {

private static int windowWidth = 500;
private static int windowHeight = 500;

private static JFrame frame;
private static JMenuBar menuBar;

public static void main(String[] args){
    build();
}

private static void build(){
    windowGen();
    menuGen();
}

private static void windowGen(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(windowWidth,windowHeight);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void menuGen(){
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem menuFileExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    menuFile.add(menuFileExit);

    menuBar.add(menuFile);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}   
}
```

do any of you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: Add it before you display the frame

Comment: Right, `setVisible(true)` needs to be the last thing you call, because that's when all the components are laid out.  If you need to modify the menu bar, that's a little different.

Comment: ahhhh excellent thank you =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to its static variable declared above, but do not create a new one, it is a first error, and another is not to define a Layout for your JFrame

```
public class GUITest {

private static int windowWidth = 500;
private static int windowHeight = 500;

private static JFrame frame;
private static JMenuBar menuBar;

public static void main(String[] args){
    build();
}

private static void build(){
    windowGen();
    menuGen();
}

private static void windowGen(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(windowWidth,windowHeight);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void menuGen(){
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem menuFileExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    menuFile.add(menuFileExit);

    menuBar.add(menuFile);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}   
}
```

Comment: so do i remove the static variable at the top?
or simply remove the word JFrame as you have above?
i have deliberately not assigned a layout as i have a small amount of experience with layouts and want to teach myself how to use without one

Comment: for this example it would be enough to remove the JFrame class before, because if it was not creating a new variable

Comment: i have just tried both of these without result:
1) removing the word JFrame as you showed (same with menu bar)
2) initialising them at the top instead

with no result, perhaps i understood your comment wrong? what intrigues me is that my window still appears just not the menu?

Comment: I answered my answer with the complete code, verify and comment , update the page

Comment: sorry im new to this website, i can only see the code for that one method, is this what yo mean? as i have tried that with no success, sorry, i'm sure my n00bness is frustrating